# On priority inversion issue, should we change the attribute of mutex or thread?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I had recently seen a fix on mutex time out issue. The mutex timeout was happening because of the priority inversion. However, I am confused with the fix that the developer has changed the mutex attribute to priority inheritance rather than the thread attribute to priority inheritance. I am confused on what should be changed. How to determine which should be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POSIX only defines a priority-inheritance protocol through mutexes.  If some system offers priority inheritance defined inside a thread attribute, that's a system extension.